# error in using sha1 function in tinyecc

Tags: sha1, tinyos

When I try to use the SHA1 function in tinyecc-2.0 IN TINYOS-2.1.2, i get the following error:

IN the configuration file I give,

```
implementation {
  components DisseminationC as App;

  App.SHA1 -> SHA1M;
}
```

Here SHA1.nc is the interface file and SHA1M.nc is the module file.

When i do `make micaz sim`, i get an error:

```
In component `DisseminationAppC':
DisseminationAppC.nc:19: expected component `SHA1', but got a component
DisseminationAppC.nc:31: cannot find `SHA1M'
```

HOW TO SOLVE THIS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't instantiate a component named SHA1M. Try this:

```
implementation {
     components DisseminationC as App;
     components SHA1M;

     App.SHA1 -> SHA1M;
}
```